# Fastest way to replace string patterns by mask

Tags: php

I have string like

```
$string = "string_key::%foo%:%bar%";
```

, and array of params

```
$params = array("foo" => 1, "bar" => 2);
```

How can I replace this params in $string pattern? 
Expected result is

```
string_key::1:2
```

Comment: What's the fastest depends on how big the search string is and how many replacement values you expect to have.

Comment: [Regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) are the fastes always..

Comment: I try to solve it with regexp, but failed =(

Comment: @user1996959 show us the code you've tried to make, someone might be able to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to rewrite the `$params` array:

```
$string = "string_key::%foo%:%bar%";
$params = array("foo" => 1, "bar" => 2);
foreach($params as $key => $value) {
    $search[] = "%" . $key . "%";
    $replace[] = $value;
}
```

After that, you can simply pass the arrays to `str_replace()`:

```
$output = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

<sup>[View output on Codepad](http://codepad.org/fCbfkwXn)</sup>

Comment: I try this way, but it not works in next cases: $search = array( "%bar%","%foo%"); and $search = array( "%foo1%", %bar%","%foo%");

Comment: That should work just fine. I just updated my code so you don't have to rewrite the `$params` array yourself, can you try again?

Answer (score 2):

On a personal note, I did this one:

```
$string = "string_key::%foo%:%bar%";
$params = array("%foo%" => 1, "%bar%" => 2);
$output = strtr($string, $params);
```

You do not have to do anything else because if there is some value in the array or the string is not replaced and overlooked.

Fast and simple method for pattern replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what will be the fastest solution for you (it depends on the string size and the number of replacement values you will use).

I normally use this kind of function to perform parameterized replacements. It uses `preg_replace_callback` and a closure to perform the replacement for each percent enclosed word.

```
function replaceVariables($str, $vars)
{
    // the expression '/%([a-z]+)%/i' could be used as well 
    // (might be better in some cases)
    return preg_replace_callback('/%([^%]+)%/', function($m) use ($vars) {
        // $m[1] contains the word inside the percent signs
        return isset($vars[$m[1]]) ? $vars[$m[1]] : '';
    }, $str);
}

echo replaceVariables("string_key::%foo%:%bar%", array(
    "foo" => 1,
    "bar" => 2
));
// string_key::1:2
```

**Update**

It's different from using `str_replace()` in cases whereby a percent enclosed value is found without a corresponding replacement.

This line determines the behaviour:

```
return isset($vars[$m[1]]) ? $vars[$m[1]] : '';
```

It will replace `'%baz%'` with an empty string if it's not part of the `$vars`. But this:

```
return isset($vars[$m[1]]) ? $vars[$m[1]] : $m[0];
```

Will leave `'%baz%'` in your final string.

Comment: Seems interesting, i use string with up to 3-4 replacements, and second example works like I need.

Comment: I like this way, and i like regexp. Thanks